# the normal vector of a normal section

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm studying surfaces, and I'm using Docarmo's Book of Differential Geometry. I have a question about the normal sections of a surface. Here is the definition:[image]

The book says that the normal vector $n(p)$ of the curve $C$ it's $ \pm N(p)$ but I'm not totally convinced. Well, clearly that vector is normal to the tangent vector of the curve, but could be the binormal vector too, so I'm not sure about that.

Comment: The normal section is the curve $C_n$; not $C$.

Answer (score 1):

The author is talking about the normal vector of a specific curve, namely the one lying in the plane containing $v$ and $N_p$.  The normal vector of this curve must also lie in the plane and hence must be proportional to $N_p$.