# Are normal sections geodesics?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces, geodesic

Based on the definition of a normal section to a surface [given here][1]

I conclude that the curvature vector of the normal section must always be in the direction of the normal vector to the surface since the curve is planar and is parametrised by arc length, which means that this normal section is a geodesic (geodesic curvature is zero at every point of the curve). If no additional restrictions are given, can I say that there are infinite geodesics that pass through a given point, each one in each direction on the tangent plane at that point?
[1]: [the normal vector of a normal section](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429155/the-normal-vector-of-a-normal-section)

Comment: Slow down. You intersect a surface with a normal plane at $P$. The curvature vector of the normal section *at* $P$ is in the direction of the normal vector to the surface. Not at other points. You can choose to parametrize any (regular) curve by arclength, yes. How are you concluding that the normal section is a geodesic? This is false. Yes, there are always geodesics in every direction, but they will almost never be these normal plane sections. Once again, you're thinking that $\kappa =\pm\kappa_n$ everywhere along the normal section, and hence $\kappa_g=0$. Only at $P$ itself.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I'm concluding that intuitively, since the curve does not change its speed, the curvature (which is its acceleration) can't have a component in the direction of the tangent vector, so it must have a component on the normal and another on the normal intrinsic (cross product of the normal and the tangent vector) since those 3 vectors is a basis for $R^3$  at each point. But the curve is planar so its acceleration vector must lie in the plane at every point, therefore, it must be always in the direction of the normal vector of the surface. I'm not sure if this reasoning is ok.

Comment: The normal vector of the surface is only in that plane at $P$. Look at some actual pictures!!

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, thank you!!

Comment: You might find my differential geometry text — freely available and linked in my profile — useful.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again.